# How exactly is query charged in google cloud bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to get a better insight and intuition on how Google Cloud BigQuery Charges us for a query ($5 for TB of query as seen on the website). The confusion is, does it charge us for the size of the table/s on which the query is applied or the amount/size of data returned by the query. Like for example, let's say I have a table of size 2 GB and I run a query on it and its returns a data of size 30 MB. So will I be charged for 2GB i.e the size of the table or for 30 MB i.e the data returned by the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are charged for the number of bytes as mentioned in the answer by Mikhail.

Here is some more insights.

Big Query stores every column in a separate encrypted, compressed file. So thus running a query like "SELECT *" will process much more bytes than a query that only SELECT's a few columns.

Answer (score 3):

If you query all fields in table of 2GB - you are charged for 2GB even if size of output just 10KB
Note: you are charged not for the whole table size but for the size of fields/columns you are query in that table (unless this is external table)

> BigQuery charges for queries by using one metric: the number of bytes
>   processed. You are charged for the number of bytes processed whether
>   the data is stored in BigQuery or in an external data source such as
>   Google Cloud Storage, Google Drive, or Google Cloud Bigtable.

More details in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries